# Boundedness + convergence in $L^2_{\text{loc}}$ implies weak convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

I am reading a paper ('Hardy's inequalities revisited' by Brezis and Marcus). In one of the proofs, they write the following:
[image]

I am not sure regarding the "last assertion" part. Is it true that if a sequence is bounded in $L^2$ and converges to $0$ in $L^2_{\text{loc}}$ then it also converges weakly to $0$? I couldn't find such a result and was wondering where I could read about it.

If you need anymore details about the functions in the picture above let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\{u_n\}$ is bounded in $L^2$, then it is weakly convergent in $L^2$, we denote the weak limit by $u$. If we also have $u_n\to v$ in $L^2_{\text{loc}}$, then we have $u=v$, so $u_n$ converges to $v$ weakly in $L^2$.

Comment: @Feng So simple. You are right. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to help. I've convert my comment to a comunity-wiki answer. You may accept it and thus we can close this question.

Comment: @Feng No, bounded certainly does not imply weakly convergent. Fix $F$ and say $f_n=(-1)^nF$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Up to passing to a subsequence I think it's fine, right?

Comment: @GSofer I don't know what it means to say it's right "up to passing to a subsequence". The assertion that a bounded sequence converges in norm is the only explicit false statement I noticed, but I don't see how we'd say the proof is right except for that, because once we realize we only have a convergent subsequence I don't see how the rest of the proof is supposed to go\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been answered in the comments, so I put it here as a community-wiki.

**Third-party edit:** Since Feng has been encouraging me to add to this answer I'll point out that it doesn't seem necessary to acknowledge the comments, because  the argument in the comments is wrong, or at least majorly incomplete. The argument below is entirely different (also correct).

Let $\Omega$ be an open set. If $u_n\to u$ in $L^2_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, then $\langle u_n,\varphi\rangle\to \langle u,\varphi \rangle$ for all $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. Since $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^2$ and $\{u_n\}$ is bounded in $L^2$, we can prove the weakly convergent of $u_n$ to $u$.

(Talking about $\phi\in L^2$ concentrated on a set with finite measure instead of $\phi\in C^\infty_c$ gives an argument that works in any measure space...)

Comment: Maybe we can do a subsequence principle argument. Since the weak* topology is metrizable,  it suffices to show that every subsequence  of $(u_n)$ has a subsequence that converges weakly to $0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I've editted my answer. Is it OK now?

Comment: Great. I was about to post a more detailed version of the same argument

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Now you can add your details to this community-wiki, if you want. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @Mason Perhaps. But in fact, as you see from the revised answer, it's all much simpler than that, no need for any compactness argument (it's really just a "let $\epsilon>0$..." thing.)